# Is there other way to set url using route?

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

i'm just starting to learn ajax laravel im just following a tutorial then it not working for me. thanks

my ajax looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#courseTable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        url: "{{{ route('courses.index') }}}",
      },
```

then in routes:

```php
Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController');
```

then for my coursecontroller:

```
public function index()
{
  // $courses = Course::orderBy('description','asc')->paginate(8);
  if (request()->ajax()) {
      return datatables()->of(Course::latest()->get())
              ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->courseID.'"
                class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</button>';
                $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->courseID.'"
                class="delete btn btn-warning btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                return $button;
              })
              ->rawColumns(['action'])
              ->make(true);
  }
  return view('registrar.courses.index');
  // ->with('courses', $courses)
}
```

this error shows up like this:

> app.js:16034 GET http://odrs.test/%7B%7B%7B%20route('courses.index')%20%7D%7D%7D?draw=1&colum 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is your ajax code in a `.blade.php` file?

Comment: no sir. its in a separate file then call it in my blade.php file

Comment: If it's not in a `.blade.php` file, you can't use blade syntax (`{{ }}`, `{!! !!}`, etc.) You'll have to find another way to define that route and use it there. Perhaps define it as a variable in your `.blade.php` file before including the JS?

Answer (score 0):

**it's impossible to write a blade template in a separate javascript file.**

you have probably 2 ways to do it:

1. join your eventListener in your blade view as a  child.
2. transfer your JS file to your views file, change its extension to blade.php and include it in the view between script tags:

```php
<script>
@include("my-view-js")
</script>
```

Comment: i tried the 2nd option how do i save my-view-js.blade.php. it returning $ not defined error?

Comment: you got the error cause you didn't include jquery on your view file

Comment: thank sir. its working now even though the datatable is deformed